# Nifi: How to pass Python's output from ExecuteScript to PutEmail body without writing to a file

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, apache-nifi

I'm very new to Nifi and I was wondering if I can pass Python's output (stdout,pandas df,markdown) from ExecuteScript without writing the output to a file in order to send out an email with PutEmail as part of the body in the email.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by writing to the flowfile in your `ExecuteScript`. E.g.:

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

# Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write()
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
      # Write to flowfile
      out = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + ' Bar'
      outputStream.write(bytearray(out.encode('utf-8')))
# end class

flowFile = session.get()
if(flowFile != None):
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
        # Last operation is transfer to success (failures handled in the catch block)
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(repr(e))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
# implicit return at the end
```

I tested it with following flow:

[image]

I set `GenerateFlowFile` Custom Text to *Foo*, let `ExecuteScript` add *Bar* to it and write the result to the flowfile. Same applies to your use case. Simply let your script write content to the flowfile. `PutEmail` will take this content and send it via email.

Learn how to master ExecuteScript: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922

Comment: One thing I'll mention is that you won't be able to use `pandas` with ExecuteScript as it is a CPython module and ExecuteScript uses Jython which doesn't allow CPython modules, only modules written strictly in Python (with no CPython dependencies)

Comment: Thank you guys. It looks promising. let me give it a try but since i'm new to Nifi, it may take a bit of to get my head around your answer but if it is correct, I'll come back to accept it.